# Landsat Analysis Ready Data (ARD) in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat

I asked [Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance Values extracted from QGIS and Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403242) about getting different values when extracting to points in both Google Earth Engine and QGIS, and I realized that I unknowingly used images from different Landsat collections (Landsat ARD images in QGIS and Landsat Collection 2 Surface Reflectance in Earth Engine). I would like to stick with the ARD images if possible, but I can't seem to find access to that data set within Earth Engine.

Does anyone know if Landsat Analysis-Ready Data is available in Google Earth Engine or will I have to import downloaded images if I want to use that data set?

Answer (score 2):

Data products like Landsat ARD are generally not added to Earth Engine's data catalog, because their primary advantage is having been reprojected onto a common grid for convenient computation, whereas Earth Engine is designed to operate readily on image collections where each image may have a distinct projection. Thus, providing such data sets would require additional storage for little benefit.

If you want to produce similar results for comparison, make sure to specify the same coordinate system when computing in Earth Engine, so that approximately the same resampling effects occur.